# Conjectured closed form for ${\it {Li_2}} \left( 1-{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2}}-i \left( 1-{\frac {\sqrt { 2}}{2}} \right) \right)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, closed-form, conjectures, polylogarithm

With Maple i find this closed form:

${\it {Li_2}} \left( 1-{\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2}}-i \left( 1-{\frac {\sqrt {
2}}{2}} \right)  \right)$=$-{\frac {{\pi}^{2}}{64}}-{\frac { \left( \ln  \left( 1+\sqrt {2}
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{2}}-{\frac {{\it {Li_2}} \left( -1-\sqrt {2}
 \right) }{2}}+{\frac {i}{32}} \left( 4\,\pi\,\ln  \left( 1+\sqrt {2}
 \right) -24\,G \right)$

where $G$ is the Catalan's constant and $Li_2$ is the dilogarithm function or Spence's function.

If you have got any ideas please for proving this identity.

Comment: Well, do you know the numerical values of those both. If yes then please let me know.

Comment: the value is about 0.2851711-0.340859i